# Array to string convert error $searchResult[]

Tags: magento2

Whats wrong in the below code:

```
$var1 = $this->myhelper->getMyData();
$searchResult = $var1 ;
foreach($searchResult['results'] as $i => $productId) {
    $orderString[] = 'WHEN '.$productId.' THEN '.$i;  //err here
}
```

I get:

> Notice: Array to string conversion error in $orderString[]

Output for `$searchResult`:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Well, are you sure, that `$searchResult['results']` exists and is an array?
You could `var_dump($searchResult)` to see what is inside...

Comment: Yes i get the values in array...but why conversion error?

Comment: Can you share the output of `var_dump`?

Comment: I have posted the output screen

Comment: Ok thanks, @ps202, issue seems to be fixed, problem from the client side configuration, i changed in my query

Comment: Cool, I am happy that you found the problem! As Siarhey wrote below, there was no `results` key in the array, that is why I wanted to see a var_dump. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have no key `results` inside the `$searchResult` array. Try to change your code from the:

```
foreach($searchResult['results'] as $i => $productId) {
    $orderString[] = 'WHEN '.$productId.' THEN '.$i;  //err here
}
```

to the:

```
foreach($searchResult as $i => $productId) {
    $orderString[] = 'WHEN '.$productId.' THEN '.$i;  //err here
}
```

But if you need the product id (not the sku) you should make some changes to the code ( where you recive the data) , because the array has only `sku`.

Comment: Thanks @Siarhey, problem was in my query, i had changed, its working now